# Combine two API from elasticsearch and PostgreSQL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest, elasticsearch

I have API

```
using elasticsearchrepository
@Autowired
private SinhvienesRepo sinhvienesrepo;
using PostgreSQL jparepository
@Autowired
private SinhvienRepo sinhvienrepo;

@GetMapping("/sinhvienes")
Iterable<Sinhvienes> Sinhvienes() {
    return sinhvienesrepo.findAll();
}


@GetMapping("/sinhviens")
List<Sinhvien> Sinhvien() {
    return sinhvienrepo.findAll();
}
```

it work well

but now I want to combine them when I request the parameter isEs == true I use this API of elasticsearch
and else I want to use API of PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use [params](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) field of the `@GetMapping` annotation:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/sinhvienes", params = "isEs=true")
    public String sinhvienEs() {
        return "ES";
    }


    @GetMapping("/sinhvienes")
    public String sinhvien() {
        return "NO ES";
    }
}
```